# R version 3.2.3, x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit); Separate RStudio windows post-installation?

Tags: rstudio

I want the RStudio console in a separate window.  I realize I can reinstall and choose a separate window option upon installation, but I'd like to avoid that.

I tried Tools -> Global Options -> Pane Layout, but to no avail.

Comment: ...and what is the point of having the console in a separate window?

Comment: to perform tasks without blocking the editor and other windows since I only have a single monitor